# Missing required icon files in build from Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, app-store-connect

Using Xcode 9 and Application Loader:

[image]

But as you can see there are all required icons:

[image]

What is the case?

This is my podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

def pods
    
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'PickerView'
    pod 'SWNavigationController'
    pod 'Branch'
    pod 'JTAppleCalendar', :git => 'https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
end

def universal_pods

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'MagicalRecord'
end

target 'FieldService' do
    
    pods
    universal_pods
end

target 'FieldServiceTests' do
    
    pods
    universal_pods
end

target 'FieldServiceTodayTimer' do
    universal_pods
end

target 'FieldServiceTodayCurrent' do
    universal_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
    copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-FieldService/Pods-FieldService-resources.sh"
    string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
    assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
    text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
    new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
    File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end

inhibit_all_warnings!
```

and it doesn't work at all.

### Edit

[image]
[image]

```
Contents.json:              ASCII text
Icon-60.png:                PNG image data, 60 x 60, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-60@2x.png:             PNG image data, 120 x 120, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-60@3x.png:             PNG image data, 180 x 180, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-76.png:                PNG image data, 76 x 76, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-76@2x.png:             PNG image data, 152 x 152, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Small.png:             PNG image data, 29 x 29, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Small@2x-1.png:        PNG image data, 58 x 58, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Small@2x.png:          PNG image data, 58 x 58, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Small@3x.png:          PNG image data, 87 x 87, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-40.png:      PNG image data, 40 x 40, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-40@2x-1.png: PNG image data, 80 x 80, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-40@2x.png:   PNG image data, 80 x 80, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-40@3x.png:   PNG image data, 120 x 120, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-41.png:      PNG image data, 40 x 40, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-42.png:      PNG image data, 40 x 40, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-Spotlight-43.png:      PNG image data, 20 x 20, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
Icon-iPadPro@2x.png:        PNG image data, 167 x 167, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
fieldservice.png:           PNG image data, 1024 x 1024, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Comment: Can you `cd` to the `AppIcon.appiconset`-Folder and paste the result of `file *` to your question? Maybe some of your icons have the wrong dimension by accident (or correct dimensions and wrong assigned "slot").

Comment: Totally shot in the dark: it seems a bit weird to me to have "Icon-..." in "AppIcon.appiconset". File names are usually start with appiconset name, for example: "AppIcon.appiconset"->"AppIcon-iPadPro@2x.png"

Comment: @MertBuran Does it matter? Is it really solution for that problem?

Comment: No :) As I said that was a shot in the dark, your project settings look fine and that was the only thing that seemed unusual to me. If you run out of solutions, you may try to re-generate your xcassets as a last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Daniel Kuta said the solution is:

1. locate your app's xcarchive file,
2. show package contents >> products >> applications >> your application's name >> show package contents.
3. Locate the info plist from here, and change the **BuildMachineOsBuild** to **16A323**.

However above solution will remove first three errors, but not the last one warning.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure `Copy Bundle Resources` is under `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` and `[CP] Copy Pods Resources` in Build Phases.

[image]

Comment: Really? Does it matter?

Comment: If you're experiencing this issue and using Cocoapods, this should be the FIRST thing you check as it's always been the cause in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. Check this: [solution](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003)

Just add this code below to your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
        copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-resources.sh"
        string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
        assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
        text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
        new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
        File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
      end
    end
```

and then run in console `pod install`

EDIT:

If its not working, locate your app's xcarchive file, right click >> show package contents, navigate to products >> applications >> your application's name >> show package contents. Locate the info plist from here, and change the BuildMachineOsBuild to 16A323. This basically tricks the computer into thinking it's on an older OS.. problem seems to stem from High Sierra. Then submit the app.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question... it seems to not working;(

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by using a combination of all three solutions found here in addition to changing other plist entries. I still got the warning about the marketing image but it worked no problem for submission.

Answer (score 4):

After trying some of the suggestions above which removed some errors, in my case I could solve all of them by renaming the AppIcon in the project's .xcassets file. The project uses CocoaPods and some of these pods contain example projects with AppIcon in it as well. So instead of removing these I simply renamed my AppIcon and changed the reference in project settings. From that moment on, it finally processed after hours of trial and error.

When looking in the Pods xcassets files with Xcode they were missing the marketing icon and the iPad Pro icon definition (older libraries). These were the exact errors I got. In the archive the files are now named AppIcon and so are they referenced in Info.plist file.

PS: to find out if you have multiple AppIcon assets, you can use `find . -name AppIcon*`

Comment: I spent an entire day messing around with this issue until I read this answer! I tried all the suggestion including the pod fix! To fix the problem, I renamed my 'AppIcon' default entry in the project's .xcassets file, and also updated the 'Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name' to align with this new value. Finally can see my beautiful icons on the home screen.

Comment: This was my fix as well. One of my pods must have had an AppIcon in it. Thanks! EDIT - It was GoogleMapsDemos

Answer (score 2):

- Archive project as usual
- On latest build in organizer from context menu pick 'Reveal in finder'
- On archive file in finder from context menu pick 'Show package contents'
- Open terminal and CD to this folder
- Run this command in terminal:

> find Products/ -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 16A323

Then proceed with regular upload. At the end you'll see a warning popup about missing marketing icon but build will go through

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue.
Fixed by removing `CFBundleIcons~ipad` key from info.plist

[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0MbQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my case one of Pods has **.xcassets** with resources. Errors with icons gone after excluding this pod. Finally pod was fixed by replacing **.xcassets** with **.bundle**.

Part of .podspec change log:

```
-  s.resources = '**/*.xcassets'
+  s.resources = '**/*.bundle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please move AppIcon to default Assets.xcassets instead Icon.xcassets.

Also here are some tips...
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html

I suggest to keep old icon names even if apple says that it isn't mandatory.