# The bundle doesn't contain an iMessage icon. iMessage app icons must be 120x90 pixels in .png format

Tags: ios, image, png, imessage

We are facing error/issue while we submitting app on app store. please check the error screenshot:  [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq8xT.png)
This error occurs when validating.
Below is the i Message icon and its info which we used
[iMessage app icon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lnTp.png)

The error message is "The bundle doesn't contain an iMessage icon. iMessage app icons must be 120x90 pixels in .png format"

Is it an xcode issue OR issue with the image?

Comment: If you’re Project is an old project, remove the specified icon (iMessage) from the plist’s list of included icons.

Comment: No, its new project

Comment: try ur luck bro

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462871/missing-required-icon-files-in-build-from-xcode-9/46799223#46799223

Comment: @VijayAvhad Check if your plist contains that icon.

Comment: there is not plist,  build in x-code 9  and Assets.xcassets is there

Comment: @VijayAvhad i hope u got ur answer by now .. Long Live I2e :)

Comment: @siddhesh, thanx for your help, we got the solution